# How to use {name:value} pairs with Gorilla Mux HandleFunc?

Tags: go, gorilla

I use a mux router with a function handler

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/test/{myfirst}/{mysecond}/{third:[0-9]+}",TestHandler)
```

The test handler is defined as follows:

```
func TestHandler(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    response.Header().Set("Content-type", "text/html")
    err := request.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(response, fmt.Sprintf("error parsing url %v", err), 500)
    }
    vars := mux.Vars(request)
    first := vars["myfirst"]
    second := vars["mysecond"]
    third := vars["mythird"]
}
```

I call the page with

```
http://localhost/test/first/second/third/1234
```

But I get a 404. Also third:value didn't work. What is the right url? And can I retrieve vars of a name/value pair like this?

Comment: that's not how you define variable paths in gorilla. their example is `r.HandleFunc("/articles/{category}/{id:[0-9]+}", ArticleHandler)` - its should be a regex to capture part of the path.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I tried that. It's in the documentation, but still I can't find a url that is recognized by the handler. I also get a 404 with the change you suggest.

Comment: in the case of their example the url should be `/articles/sports/145`. You can's use `x=y` in paths before the `?` for GET parameters.

Comment: Hi, I changed it in the code above and also tried it with the same result. Did you mean as I wrote above?